# cannot find the class responsible for NotSerializableException

Tags: java, spring, serializable, notserializableexception

I had a problem in my application

```
 java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate
```

and I changed the javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD from client to server and it resolved my problem.

```
 BEFORE
 <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>

AFTER
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>SERVER</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It works ok, but I read that with such an error, the class reponsible is displayed in the stacktrace, which was not the case, so I wonder where this error came from (PS; I use lazy loading when displaying data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error came from a Bean that had ViewScope, I changed in into SessionScope and now it works